.net core 6, blazor server, "A task was canceled" when OnInitializedAsync queries EFCore. Only when page path is not "/"
sorry for the cryptic subject.
My Blazor Server App (.net core 6), has a page in root "/". In the OnInitializedAsync I make an async read to EFCore. So far, works like a charm.
When I change the route to "/setup", then I receive an "A task was canceled" error in the same EFCore read. (source: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational). The exception detail is:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.<OpenInternalAsync>d__70.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.<OpenInternalAsync>d__70.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.<OpenAsync>d__66.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<InitializeReaderAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass33_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteImplementationAsync>d__34`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteImplementationAsync>d__34`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__33`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNextAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__65`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__65`1.MoveNext()
   at X.Connectors.Y.v10.Services.Connector.Setups.ConnectorSetupService.<X-Connectors-Y-v10-Interface-Services-Connector-IConnectorSetupService-GetSetups>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Git\X.Connectors.Y.v10\X.Connectors.Y.v10.Services\Connector\Setups\ConnectorSetupService.cs:line 113

Maybe sharing with you the App.razor could be useful...
<CascadingBlazoredModal>
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
</CascadingBlazoredModal>

EDITED AFTER COMMENTS...
I'm not navigating. I've just replaced this
this
@page "/"
to this
@page "/setup"

My init code looks like this...
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        setups = await connectorSetupService.GetSetups();
        if (setups.Any())
            setup = await connectorSetupService.GetSetup(setups.First().Id);

        loading = false;
    }


And the method I'm calling is from a service that directly access to dbcontext (via injection)
        async Task<List<SetupTinyDto>> IConnectorSetupService.GetSetups()
        {
            var setups = await _dbContext.Setups.AsNoTracking().Where(s => s.IsDeleted == false).ToListAsync();
            return _mapper.Map<List<SetupTinyDto>>(setups);
        }


No IDbContextFactory. Just injectinc DBContext

All service registrations add "AddScope". The DB is "AddDbContext" with SQL Server.


Thank you in advance.

Post the OnInitializedAsync code at least, any Dispose methods and ConnectorSetupService, the code that actually throws. As for When I change the route to "/setup" that's a navigation to a different page which means the current page/component is disposed and any pending operations will be orphaned and garbage collected. A common way to cancel pending operations when navigating away from a page is to signal cancellation in the component's Dispose/DisposeAsync method

It's unclear if the error occurs when you are navigating from "/" to "/setup" or if you've changed the actual page name on the component.  In either case we need to be able to see App.razor - not Routes.razor you have shown and OnInitializedAsync.  Are you using a single DbContext or an IDbContextFactory.

Thank you. I've edited the post after your comments, to be more clear. @PanagiotisKanavos, I understand what you mean, but don't know how yo apply that in my code. MrC aka Shaun Curtis, the App.razor is already in the post. (this is a Blazor Server btw). Answered there your questions. Tx!
